# Use Groovy Category implicitly in all instance methods of class

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, categories, metaclass

I have simple Groovy category class which adds method to String instances:

```
final class SampleCategory {

    static String withBraces(String self) {
        "($self)"
    }

}
```

I want to use this category in my unit tests (for example). It looks like this:

```
class MyTest {
    @Test
    void shouldDoThis() {
        use (SampleCategory) {
            assert 'this'.withBraces() == '(this)'
        }
    }

    @Test
    void shouldDoThat() {
        use (SampleCategory) {
            assert 'that'.withBraces() == '(that)'
        }
    }
}
```

What I'd like to achieve, however, is ability to specify that category `SampleCategory` is used in scope of each and every instance method of `MyTest` so I don't have to specify `use(SampleCategory) { ... }` in every method.

Is it possible?

Comment: Should be doable with AST transformations, not sure how to implement it tho. There's a section in the userguide [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compile-time+Metaprogramming+-+AST+Transformations) and Hamlet D'arcy talks about it in his ["Code generation on the JVM"](http://hamletdarcy.blogspot.com/2010/07/code-generation-on-jvm-video-and-slides.html)-talk (not sure how deep he goes). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for idea! Sounds like a good small OSS project candidate :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use mixin to apply the category directly to String's metaClass.  Assign null to the metaClass to reset it to groovy defaults.  For example:

```
@Before void setUp() { 
    String.mixin(SampleCategory)
}

@After void tearDown() {
    String.metaClass = null
}

@Test
void shouldDoThat() {
    assert 'that'.withBraces() == '(that)'
}
```

Comment: Did you actually try this out? I came up with an almost identical solution, tested it out, and it didn't work.

Comment: ataylor, thank you, solution really works and it's quite elegant! I made couple of minor changes (e.g. use of @BeforeClass/@AfterClass)

Comment: Great, I figured there would be an eaier way than doing custom AST programming :) Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Now you have the option to use **extension modules** instead of categories:
http://mrhaki.blogspot.se/2013/01/groovy-goodness-adding-extra-methods.html

On the plus side Intellij will recognize the extensions. I've just noticed that it doesn't even need to be a separate module as suggested by the link, just add META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule to the project:

```
# File: src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule
moduleName = module
moduleVersion = 1.0
extensionClasses = SampleExtension
```

The extension class is pretty much defined like a normal category:

```
class SampleExtension {
    static String withBraces(String self) {
        "($self)"
    }
}
```

Can be used like:

```
def "Sample extension"() {
    expect: 'this'.withBraces() == '(this)'
}
```

If you are using **Spock** there is a @Use annotation that can be used on the specifications. The drawback with that is that Intellij will not recognize it.