# Use Groovy Category DSL implicitly in all methods of class

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, dsl

I have a complicated Groovy category which defines my DSL language. For example it contains something like:

```
class MyDSL {

    static Expr getParse(String expr) {
        Parser.parse(expr)
    }

    static Expr plus(Expr a, Expr b){
        a.add(b)
    }

    ...
}
```

The `MyDSL` category contains DSL elements for many types of objects (not only `String` and `Expr`). I can use my DSL in another class by using the `use` keyword:

```
class MyAlgorithm {

    Expr method1(Expr expr) {
        use(MyDSL) {
            def sum = 'x + y'.parse
            return sum + expr        
        }

    Expr method2(String t) {
        use(MyDSL) {
            def x = t.parse
            return method1(x) + x        
        }

    ...
}
```

Can I do something to avoid writing of `use` keyword each time in each method? I also would like still to have code completion and syntax highlighting in my IDE (IntelliJ perfectly recognises DSL inside `use`).

There is similar question [Use Groovy Category implicitly in all instance methods of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552180/use-groovy-category-implicitly-in-all-instance-methods-of-class) about avoiding `use` in unit tests, but I need to do the same in main classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no way to implement this other than using an AST to insert it automatically into each method. Even then, i doubt IntelliJ would recognize it.

Another path, which IntelliJ won't ever recognize, is intercepting `invokeMethod`:

```
class Captain {
  def sayWot() {
    "my string".foo()
  }

  def sayNigh() {
    9.bar()
  }
}

Captain.metaClass.invokeMethod = { String name, args ->
  def self = delegate
  def method = self.metaClass.getMetaMethod name, args
  use(MyCategory) { 
    method.invoke self, args 
  }
}

class MyCategory {
  static foo(String s) {
    s + " foo"
  }
  static bar(Integer i) {
    i + " bar"
  }
}

c = new Captain()

assert c.sayWot() == 'my string foo'
assert c.sayNigh() == '9 bar'
```